# call cmd from shortcut with custom title

Tags: windows, cmd

i have a shortcut to cmd.exe.

Is it possible to change cmd window title when I run it from this shortcut ?

Comment: Renaming the shortcut to the title you want could do the trick. This worked for me on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
C:\> cmd /k "title MyWindow"
```

---

```
`cmd /K`      => Carries out the command specified by string but remains
`title [str]` => Specifies the title for the command prompt window.
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible. You will need to create a shortcut to a batch file that run cmd.exe with your custom window title, something like this:

```
start "MyWindow" cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

This works when launching from a CMD script
(launches CMD in specific user context with a specific title)

```
runas /savecred /user:domain\user "%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe /K title BAD MF"
```